Hard disk issues in Android
I have Samsung SSD hard disk. I copy files from my Android device to hardDisk. Multiple times I disconnected hardDisk and connected hardDisk to phone and it worked fine.
After a day when I connected the hard disk to Android phone then I get error that I need to format the hardDisk to be able to use it. When I connect the same hardDisk to Windows Laptop or MACbook then it still works fine. In MAC I ran the FirstAid in Disk utility app and even that says the hardDisk is fine.
The hardDisk is formatted as exFAT. How do I find a permanent solution or a workaround? I want to be able to copy copying files from phone to hardDisk directly instead of copying files from phone -> computer -> hardDisk.
I tried with Seagate HDD and faced the same problem.

FAT32 may be more standard on both devices.

Possible dupes: What file systems can I use for a 128GB sdcard on Android 7.1, used as portable storage, Best file system for an external SD card

Make sure to always reject to disk on software level (notification area should contain an entry to reject it) before disconnecting the USB connection. Otherwise you will get problems earlier or later no matter what file-system you use.
